# How to get info on an specific active firebird transaction ID (e.g. determine which tables are affected)

Tags: transactions, firebird, firebird2.5

In some rare circumstances users report a "lock conflict no wait transaction deadlock" error in our application which is using a firebird database (V2.5). Obviously we forgot to commit a transaction (we can NOT use auto-commit!) - or it's simply a timing issue.

To get more info where the problem comes from, I'd like to know what SQL-statement caused the problem or at least which table entry was causing the error. I can't remote-debug the app, but I can have access to the DB.

In the error message I get the transaction ID. I can hook up on the PC and when entering "select * from MON$TRANSACTIONS;" in isql I get a list of open transactions. The "bad" transaction-ID is there.

Is there any possibility to get more information on that specific transaction? Like the DDL, SQL-statements "in" the transaction, or the name of the affected table(s), maybe even the affected row/column of the table?

Comment: AFAIK, no, or only with limited/incomplete information.

Comment: Have you tried to query `MON$STATEMENTS` table for transaction id?

Comment: Rene: Thanks. I tried that, but it returned only
MON$STATEMENT_ID MON$ATTACHMENT_ID MON$TRANSACTION_ID MON$STATE             MON$TIMESTAMP      MON$SQL_TEXT  MON$STAT_ID
================
              65              3279              16116         1 2016-08-29 11:15:16.8570                0:2            5
================
MON$SQL_TEXT:
Select * from MON$TRANSACTIONS